# How to set the text of a TextView to the content of a selected item on a spinner?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm trying to get the value of the selected item into a TextView, and i want it to change each time the selected item change!
I've try to get the position of the selected item into a string then set the text of the TextView equal to this same string but no sucess ! I'm really really new on java coding, all answer is really welcome !

Main Activity:

```js
package com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.array.godsNames;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.id.god_List;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.id.selected_God;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.string.selected_god;


public class ultimate extends AppCompatActivity {
        Spinner gl;
        String god1;
        TextView selectedGod;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ultimate);
        selectedGod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_God);
        selectedGod.setText(selected_god);
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }


    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        gl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.god_List);
        gl.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());


    }

    public void get_name(View view) {
        Spinner god_List = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.god_List);
        god1 = god_List.getSelectedItem().toString();
        TextView selectedGod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_God);
        selectedGod.setText(god1);
    }
}
```

MyOnItemSelectedListener() :

```js
package com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.R.attr.y;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.id.god_List;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.id.selected_God;
import static com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.R.string.selected_god;


public class MyOnItemSelectedListener extends ultimate implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            String result = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

            selectedGod.setText(result);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected God : " + result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        }
    }
```

The logcat:

```html
03-05 15:12:09.966 19007-19007/com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown, PID: 19007
                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                at com.barcala.android.smiteultimatecountdown.MyOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(MyOnItemSelectedListener.java:26)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1124)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:54)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:1089)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above your line for the Toast, put this line:

```
g1.setText(mAdapter.getItem(adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

But for it to work you need to make your adaptor accessible. So set the adapter up next to the "TextView g1" and put them at the top of the Activity rather than inside the listener:

```
TextView g1;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter;
```

**Edit** in response to comment:

Put the g1 and mAdapter at the top of the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity {

    TextView mG1;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter;
    ...
}
```

Comment: First thank you for the answer, but when I put the g1.set Text the "getSelectedItem" don't work. It don't recognize it.

Comment: getSelectedItem not working because of the static context ? I don't really now what it means but it's not working, i've updated my first edit

Comment: getSelectedItem will not work. When you say "getItem" it expects an int for the postion. Use getSelectedItemPosition as suggested in my answer. Or even easier, use "pos".

Comment: Still not working ... Look I'm gone change my first edit with what a found, can you help me with my logcat ?

Comment: You're solution is essentially the same as what I proposed. However you shouldn't post a new answer. That's bad form. Just amend it to your question and accept this answer. I provided you free help, the least you can do is accept the answer.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry it's my first post, i don't want to offend you !

Comment: Also, anyone can edit other people's answers or questions. It needs to be peer reviewed (someone else must accept your edit), but if you felt that my answer could be updated then you're free to modify it. Try not to change your original question except to clarify it. The question and answer should be separate so other readers can understand it easily. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

string.xml

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Array Item One</item>
<item>Array Item Two</item>
<item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

layout

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/array_name"
    />
```

Activity class

```
String[] myarray;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name);
}
```

your class

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    TextView g1;


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {



                 String result = myarray[pos]; 
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Country : " + result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                g1.setText(result);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me, I've tried your method but it crash when the apk start running... Maybe it's somewhere else on my code ?

Comment: And how can you set the text on a TextView?

Comment: When i run it logcast "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array"

Comment: to set text |


g1.setText(result);

look at the code that I edited

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
that is another problem,, 
have you added array in string.xml?

Comment: Yes I have a string-array with all my items

Comment: Ok i find a solution ! Thx for helping me !!